# Как написать regex, не принимающий пустую строку?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно, чтобы выражение могло читать: символ `-`, либо же слово состоящее из букв `KQkq`. Порядок важен, каждая буква может присутствовать ноль либо один раз. Слово должно состоять минимум из одной буквы.

Я написал такое выражение `(-|K?Q?k?q?)`, но оно, к сожалению принимает и пустую строку. Есть идеи как его можно улучшить?

Строки которые должны приниматься

```
-
KQkq
K
Q
Qk
```

не должны приниматься

```
QK
QQ
     // пустая строка
qQ
```

Comment: Между буквами ничего не может стоять. Но каждая буква как может присутстовать так может и отсутствовать

Comment: Пустая строка в данном случае удовлетворяет вашему условию- что слово KQkq может встретиться, а может и не встретиться в строке.

Comment: уточнил описание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде так:

```
/^(\-|KQ?k?q?|K?Qk?q?|K?Q?kq?|K?Q?k?q)$/g
```

Проверить можете [тут](https://regex101.com/r/2rharZ/4)

Comment: ваше выражение принимает слово kkkkk

Comment: @S.G. посмотрите еще раз, обновил ответ.

Comment: подзодит! Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать

```
^(?:-|(?=.)K?Q?k?q?)$
```

или

```
^(?:-|(?!$)K?Q?k?q?)$
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/LHTd7d/1)

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?:`  - начало незхватывающей группы

  - `-`  - дефис
  - `|` или
  - `(?=.)` - блок предварительного просмотра вперед, требует наличия символа, отличного от символа перехода на новую строку сразу после текущей позиции (`(?!$)` запрещает совпадение конца строки)
  - `K?` - 1 или 0 символов `K`
  - `Q?` - 1 или 0 символов `Q`
  - `k?` - 1 или 0 символов `k`
  - `q?` - 1 или 0 символов `q`
- `)` - конец группы
- `$` - конец строки.

Comment: Очень интересное решение. Спасибо.
Можете объяснить подробнее что делает "?:" и нужно ли оно тут. Вроде все работает без этого модификатора

Comment: @S.G. Это не модификатор, это синтаксис "незхватывающей группы", то есть значение, которое находит шаблон такой группы, не сохраняется в отдельном буфере памяти.